# xslt match all nodes except a specific one

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to match all nodes in my xml except one ie docbody. Something like

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(docBody)]" name="identity">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

How do i achieve this, i tried the way above.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i tried to exclude node that way, it is not working, is there a way to exclude node in match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match all but this one (adding `self::`) and overwrite the default template for `docBody` (without it the contents of `docBody` would still be printed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::docBody)]" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- overwrite the default template -->
<xsl:template match="docBody">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: To exclude comments, would the XPath be `@*|node()[not(self::comment())]` or `@*|node()[not(//comment())]` respectively?

Answer (score 4):

Your match condition says "any node that does not have a `docBody` element *child*", which is different from not being a `docBody` element *itself*. You want this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::docBody)]" name="identity">
```

Although you should just use two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="docBody"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply need to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::docBody)]" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```