# XSL exclude not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL transformation with the following requirement :
Mirror the exact same XML excluding the DocumentList element.

The following is my code. I got this solution from :
[xslt match all nodes except a specific one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525629/xslt-match-all-nodes-except-a-specific-one)

My Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::DocumentList)]" name="identity">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- overwrite the default template -->
<xsl:template match="DocumentList">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i run my transformation, the same xml with all elements are displayed. My quiestion therefore is, do i need to specify the path in the match =" ? What is missing her?

My source XML does have othernamespaces which I did declare in the stylesheet element, but for privacy have not reproduced here.

Comment: Only posting the stylesheet code does not allow us to reproduce the problem, so you need to show minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and output you get to allow us to first reproduce and then fix the problem. If your real data can't be shown then make up some, but XML and XSLT need to match when it comes to element names and namespaces.

Comment: This issue is most probably due to the namespaces, which you have to declare at the root of your stylesheet, and use in the `match="[...]"`. It is also possible to use a `xpath-default-namespace="[...]"` declaration.

Comment: For instance http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YS has an input with a `DocumentList` element and minimal XSLT to remove it and works fine.

Comment: Thanks Guys, wil ltry these and revert but so far not working still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - this was a namspace issue. I aliased my default namespace and it worked.
ie 
instead of xmlns="default namespace url"
i used xmlns:x="default namespace url"

Thanks,
Ahmed